# Xcode Swift Calculate average of 23 Text Field values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to iOS programming. I am making an app which reads values of Text Fields and calculates the average value. I have 23 Text Fields. Here is what I have.

```
import UIKit

class SavedBerekenenViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var naam1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var naam2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer4: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer5: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging6: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer6: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging7: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer7: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging8: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer8: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging9: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer9: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging10: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer10: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging11: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer11: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging12: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer12: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging13: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer13: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging14: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer14: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging15: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer15: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging16: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer16: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging17: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer17: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging18: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer18: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging19: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer19: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging20: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer20: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging21: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer21: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging22: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer22: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var weging23: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cijfer23: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var LBgemiddelde: UILabel!

    var text: String = ""
    var I: Int = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.title = text
    }

    func gemiddelde() {
        let aantalCijfers:Double = (Double(weging1.text!)! + Double(weging2.text!)! + Double(weging3.text!)! + Double(weging4.text!)! + Double(weging5.text!)! + Double(weging6.text!) + Double(weging7.text!)! + Double(weging8.text!)! + Double(weging9.text!)! + Double(weging10.text!)! + Double(weging11.text!)! + Double(weging12.text!)! + Double(weging13.text!)! + Double(weging14.text!)! + Double(weging15.text!)! + Double(weging16.text!)! + Double(weging17.text!)! + Double(weging18.text!)! + Double(weging19.text!)! + Double(weging20.text!)! + Double(weging21.text!)! + Double(weging22.text!)! + Double(weging23.text!)!)
        let som:Double = (Double(cijfer1.text!)! * Double(weging1.text!)! + Double(cijfer2.text!)! * Double(weging2.text!) + Double(cijfer3.text!)! * Double(weging3.text!)! + Double(cijfer4.text!)! * Double(weging4.text!)! + Double(cijfer5.text!)! * Double(weging5.text!)! + Double(cijfer6.text!)! * Double(weging6.text!)! + Double(cijfer7.text!)! * Double(weging7.text!)! + Double(cijfer8.text!)! * Double(weging8.text!)! + Double(cijfer9.text!)! * Double(weging9.text!)! + Double(cijfer10.text!)! * Double(weging10.text!)! + Double(cijfer11.text!)! * Double(weging11.text!)! + Double(cijfer12.text!)! * Double(weging12.text!)! + Double(cijfer13.text!)! * Double(weging13.text!)! + Double(cijfer14.text!)! * Double(weging14.text!)! + Double(cijfer15.text!)! * Double(weging15.text!)! + Double(cijfer16.text!)! * Double(weging16.text!)! + Double(cijfer17.text!)! * Double(weging17.text!)! + Double(cijfer18.text!)! * Double(weging18.text!)! + Double(cijfer19.text!)! * Double(weging19.text!)! + Double(cijfer20.text!)! * Double(weging20.text!)! + Double(cijfer21.text!)! * Double(weging21.text!)! + Double(cijfer22.text!)! * Double(weging22.text!)! + Double(cijfer23.text!)! * Double(weging23.text!)!)
        let gemiddeldedouble:Double = (som / aantalCijfers)
        LBgemiddelde.text = String(gemiddeldedouble)
    }

    @IBAction func bereken(_ sender: UIButton) {
        gemiddelde()
    }
```

I don't think this is the proper way to do this, so please help.

Comment: Are these text fields in the same view?

Comment: yes, they are in the same view. But isn't there any faster way to do this ? And one which actually works haha

Comment: No, it has a few more textfields and 2 buttons

Comment: That is 46 text fields, not 23 text fields. I assume they are arranged in pairs. But are you sure 23 is the right number? Why not 22 pairs? Why not 24? It really looks like you ought to be using a `UITableView` or a `UICollectionView` for this, with one pair per cell.

Comment: Yes I ment 23 pairs of textfields.Those textfields are the grades which a student can get. And students hier can get 23 grades. That's the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IBOuletCollection` rather than individual `IBOulet` for `UITextField`. And just iterate into the collection and get the value of each textfield save it into variable and than get the average of those values.

```
        var allValues = 0
        for tf in txtFields {
            allValues = allValues + Int(tf.text!)!

        }
        print(allValues)
```

Comment: How can I get the value of each textfield in a variable. Could you give me an example ?

Answer (score 2):

Use IBOutletCollection or it's equivalent as follows:

> @IBOutlet var textFieldsArray: [UITextField]?

Connect all text fields to the above property. 
Then you can just iterate over all the textFields using the for-in loop in swift, get values, and calculate the average.

If you use objective-C code, connect all outlets to `IBOutletCollection`, and calculate the average using `@avg` from KVC collection operators.